# How do I run emacs from terminal? This is my first time using ubuntu

Tags: emacs

Need help getting emacs going to run program for CS I class

**EDIT**
I get an error message saying `emacs can be found in the following packages: emacs23, emacs23-nox, e3, emacs23-lucid, jove` and that I have to enable them.

Comment: You type `emacs`?

Comment: I get an error message saying "emacs can be found in the following packages: emacs23, emacs23-nox, e3, emacs23-lucid, jove- and that I have to enable them

Comment: mentioning that in the first place would have been helpful.  Do as it says and install one of the packages.  You can use the software center to do it in the gui, or run `sudo apt-get install emacs23` on the command line.

Comment: This is more an irc or forum question?

Comment: This question was indirectly helpful in answering the question "does emacs come preinstalled on ubuntu"

Answer (score 2):

First you need to install it (unless it's already installed)

Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
And enter `emacs`

You may see this

```
$ emacs
The program 'emacs' can be found in the following packages:
 * emacs23
 * emacs23-nox
 * e3
 * emacs23-lucid
 * jove
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Install the package by typing for example `sudo apt-get install emacs23`

You can now run emacs by typing `emacs` in a terminal.

Note: **emacs** is a powerful but not very intuitive editor you will need to learn how to use it.  There is a tutorial [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/) to get you started.